# Remap page up, page down, home and end to work like on PC

Tags: operating-systems

I would like to remap ⇞, ⇟, ↖ and ↘ to work like on PC. This means: go to end of line / beginning of line or to end of document / beginning of document if pressed together with control. And the page up/down which is already kind of working should move the cursor like it does on PC.

I've gotten used to ⌃←/→ but still I switch between PC and Mac continously and would like to have the convience of those keys.

Is there a mapping file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used [DoubleCommand](http://doublecommand.sourceforge.net/) to remap keys successfully on Mac OS X 10.6 Snow Leopard on a MacBook Pro.

I remapped the lower-right Option key to become a Ctrl key (I'm an emacs user, and not having Ctrl keys on both sides is a serious pain).

Comment: Works fine but it does not allow remapping PgUp/PgDown to work like on the PC. Home/End are fine. Unfortunately if you use MS RDP and connect to Windows, neither the remapped Home/End keys work, nor the CMD+Arrow Right/Left.

Answer (score 1):

You can change home and end by creating `~/Library/KeyBindings/` and save this as `DefaultKeyBinding.dict`:

```
{
    "\UF729"  = moveToBeginningOfLine:;
    "\UF72B"  = moveToEndOfLine:;
    "$\UF729" = moveToBeginningOfLineAndModifySelection:;
    "$\UF72B" = moveToEndOfLineAndModifySelection:;
    "@\UF729"  = moveToBeginningOfDocument:;
    "@\UF72B"  = moveToEndOfDocument:;
}
```

`@` = ⌘, `$` = ⇧, `\UF729` = ↖ , `\UF72B` = ↘, `\UF72C` = ⇞, `\UF72D` = ⇟

`"\UF72D"  = pageDown:;` would also make page down move the caret, but `pageDown:` does not work in web views or iWork applications.

For more information, see the [Cocoa Text System](http://hcs.harvard.edu/~jrus/site/cocoa-text.html) article, [my website](http://lri.me/keybindings.html), or [this post in the TextMate blog](http://blog.macromates.com/2005/key-bindings-for-switchers/).

Answer (score 0):

There are a few other options as well:

http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/ (which despite its name, works on all mac keyboards)

http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?site_id=nrsi&id=ukelele (this is more for remapping keyboards for multilingual purposes, but it might still suit you)

Comment: Have you actually [checked](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/list.html) to see if it's possible?